# How to get better results out of the Tesseract library?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I'm a newbie to OCR libraries and I used this app that tests Google's Tesseract library:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr&hl=en

The results were really bad. It could hardly recognize an 'r' and mostly confused it for an 'n'.

I wanted to ask if the bad results are because the Tesseract library isn't good or do the results also depend on how the app was written.

Where can I learn to use the Tesseract library and make a better app?

What library does the Google Goggles use?

Answer (score 3):

I think tesseract is probably the best open source OCR, probably better than some of the commercial ones out there. Look for accuracy tests in this paper by Goolge [An Overview of the Tesseract OCR Engine](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/33418.pdf)

Even then the error percentage may be very high. The reason is that tesseract does some image processing before it could actually perform OCR. Now the accuracy depends on the quality of image and the way that particular image is processed. See this link [Tesseract OCR Quality](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ImproveQuality). You can observe that after the processing some of the characters to be recognized are not available. Also size of the image and characters as well as the font matters.

Although tesseract is not directly implementable for all the recognition as a generic engine you can always train (Machine Learning) tesseract to recognoize text in your pictures. The application that you shared probably uses teserract as it is. When you are developing application for a specific type of recognition (Ex: licence plate, bill boards etc] you will see a lot of improvement if you can train tesseract and also provide it with processed images from which it can recognize easily.

Comment: I just tried tesseract on an 1867 German document with Fraktur font.  Results were pretty bad, BUT I could figure out every word—compared to Cisdem, which looked like two cats had been fighting on my keyboard.  Took me a while to do the test—tesseract's built-in documentation sucks.